# I want to login with both and phone number in this DRF

Tags: python-3.x, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm currently using a custom user model and can log in with my phone number. But now I want to log in with both phone and email. Please check the given code and let me know in the comments if any more details are needed. Thanks in advance.

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    phone = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers .CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        email = data. get ('email')
        phone = data.get('phone')
        password = data.get('password')
        reg = False
        print(phone, ",", password)
        obj = CustomUser.objects.get(phone=phone)
        if phone and password:
            user = authenticate(username=obj.username, password=password)
            if user:
                data['user'] = user
                print(user.id)
            else:
                msg = 'login failed'
                raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
        else:
            msg = 'provide credientials'
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
        return data
```

Comment: You should preferably do this with a custom authentication backend that extends the default model backend – that way all login forms in your app will work with phone and email.

Comment: `obj = CustomUser.objects.get(phone=phone)`, first of all, you are doing this before the line that checks if you even got a phone. Second, it should just work `obj = CustomUser.objects.get(phone=phone, email=email)`. However, keep in mind that it will throw an exception if you can't find that user. Use `filter` and `exists()` instead (then to use that object, assuming only one like that can exist use `first()`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean *User could use email OR phone to login*. Here are some feedback for your code:

- password should be `required=True`
- You should add the `email` field in the serializer. Like the `phone` field, it must be optional (`required=False`)
- In `validate`, throw an error if neither `email` nor `phone` are provided
- Also throw an error if BOTH are provided. It's email OR phone, not neither, not both.
- Make sure to have a `unique constraint` in your `User` model for the `email` and `phone` field. If they are used for auth, no user should have the same email or phone
- Then, fetch your user using either phone or email
- If you use `get`, you can do a `try/except` block on the `Model.DoesNotExists` error. Otherwise, you can use `filter` and throw an error if you did not find exactly 1 user

  - If 1 user, keep going
  - If no user, invalid credentials
  - If several users, there's a huge problem in your DB
- Assuming you found 1 user, try authenticate him

  - If success, return valid response
  - Else, return invalid creds

Do note that there are other ways of implementing this, like adding custom authentication backend as mentioned in the comments. But for now, those are some improvements you can make

Comment: This issue has been fixed. Thank you